# Dynamically find a value in between a range of Values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, dynamically-generated

In google sheets, I have a data set that identifies historical pricing multiplyers for a product in certain size ranges. I'm using square inches in this case. The data is set up in a table like this:

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd6R4.png)

What I've done is create a formula that allows me to specify any width, height and quantity, find the current square inches, then find the corresponding price for this specific sized product based on where it falls on the range of sizes that I've provided in the data set.

For example, if the square inches equals 150, the price for this size is .6 (or 60 cents) per square inch. (90)

I've already solved this. This is the formula I have:

```
=(A10*B10)*C10)*(filter(C2:C6,A2:A6<=((A10*B10)*C10),B2:B6>((A10*B10)*C10))
```

In this example, A10 = height, B10 = width, and C10 = quantity

So, like I said, this works just fine. My problem is that a product with a square inch value of 105 will ultimately have the same cost per square inch as a product with a square inch value of 214. It's only after it crosses the 250 square inch threshold that my cost per square inch will change.

Is there a way to dynamically find the appropriate multiplyer, so that, for instance, a square inch value of 175, would have a multiplyer between .8 and .6 since it falls in the middle of 100 square inches and 250 square inches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to assume that you have some kind of calculator for calculating coefficients.

If value of the area in `C13` then in `A16:C17` we can get the calculate range. Put in to `A16`

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(OFFSET(A2:C6,MATCH(C13,A2:A6,1)-2,0),2,3)
```

After that we can calculate part of price

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A16),C16-(C16-C17)*(C13-A17)/(B17-A17),C17)
```

[image]

One formula solution

```
=VLOOKUP(C13,B2:C6,2)-
  (VLOOKUP(C13,B2:C6,2)-VLOOKUP(C13,A2:C6,3))*
  (C13-VLOOKUP(C13,A2:C6,1))/
  (VLOOKUP(C13,A2:C6,2)-VLOOKUP(C13,A2:C6,1))
```

[image]

The best solution is use a TREND. It's very clear.

```
=TREND(
  OFFSET(B2,MATCH(C13,B2:B3)-1,1,2,1),
  OFFSET(B2,MATCH(C13,B2:B3)-1,0,2,1),
  C13
)
```

[image]

My [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13khHQy180y-RenOrzrEI3oRf7RJ_dCg_l_HydK6kpnE/edit?usp=sharing)

#### References

- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en)
- [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en)
- [TREND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094263?hl=en)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I trust you'll forgive me if I don't explain the math involved, but this formula should produce the result you want:

`=(A10*B10*C10)*(VLOOKUP(A10*B10*C10,A2:C6,3,TRUE)+(((A10*B10*C10)-VLOOKUP(A10*B10*C10,A2:A6,1,TRUE))*(ABS(VLOOKUP(A10*B10*C10,A2:C6,3,TRUE)-INDEX(C2:C6,MATCH(VLOOKUP(A10*B10*C10,A2:C6,3,TRUE),C2:C6,0)-1))/(VLOOKUP(A10*B10*C10,A2:B6,2,TRUE)-VLOOKUP(A10*B10*C10,A2:A6,1,TRUE)))))`

Comment: Thank you. This one didn't work for me though. It's returning a multiplier value of .733 which is incorrect. I tried, but I can't figure out why. The other answer solved my issue though. Thanks for putting this together for me.

Comment: When I ran it myself using your posted data exactly in the same ranges; and the multiplier value came up at 0.7 exactly, which it should (i.e., 175 is 75 over 100 and 75 under 250, or halfway, and halfway between 0.6 and 0.8 is 0.7).

Comment: I must be doing something wrong on my end. I'll try it again. This is great guys. I'm learning a lot =)

Comment: Feel free to share a link to a sample spreadsheet, being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." This is always the most efficient and effective way to get help.

Comment: I definitely will in the future. This is all new to me, but so far it's been very helpful